# add to cart button doesnot take select list price and weight

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I have a select list of weight that displays price accordingly
according to weight
the add to cart button takes only the first price and first weight and not others
[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify the question/what you've tried already?

Comment: instead of radio i tried select list to customize i just want it to get added to cart accordingly

Comment: Please add to your question which version of joomla, which version of virtuemart and possible extensions you are using. In what file did you make changes?

Comment: mod_virtuemart_product -> default.php  , virtuemart 2 ,joomla 2.5